# Using REST API to recieve JSON

Tags: rest-api, json, rest

I have a requirement where a client wishes to send JSON to our org.  I've not handled this before, is REST API the best way to go? They are going to use "webhooks to create and send a JSON form" to our org.  I'm going to assume they've not worked with Saleforce before and will require information from me, so how would they send the JSON to Salesforce?  In my class would I receive one String parameter - the JSON string?

Sorry if this is a bunch of novice questions, I've not used REST before!

Comment: The short answer is yes. You would need to expose a URL in sitecore using REST.  The REST of the information can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_prereq.htm).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to spend time working on something only to turn out I was using the wrong thing!